# Keycloak/Postgres Restore Process Not Picking up Changes

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

I have docker compose file which runs keycloak and postgres database running as its backend.

Here is the docker compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.0
    command: start
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"
      - "8444:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs/localhost.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./certs/localhost.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
    depends_on:
      postgres_svr:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - local

  postgres_svr:
    image: postgres:15
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200' && postgres -c 'shared_buffers=24MB'
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - local


networks:
  local:
    name: local

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I just cannot get the restore process to work.

I did the following:

1. Create users and groups within Keycloak and then took a DB backup by running

`docker exec -t container_name pg_dumpall -c -U username > dump_all.sql`

2. Deleted users and groups and carried out docker stop command for keycloak container(I've even removed it).
3. Did a restore of DB by:

```
docker cp container_name:dump_all.sql /tmp
docker exec -it container_name bash
psql -h localhost -U username -d local-db
cat backup_26012024.sql | psql -U username -d local-db
```

4. dokcer compose up -d (brings up the keycloak)

I check the user_entity table and everything is there but keycloak does not reflect this.  It shows the same users/groups before the restore process.

Can you spot where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add volumes info for your `postgres_svr` setup, like this:

```
volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```